# Use QMessageBox in PyQt5 to restart my game or exit the application

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a memory game made in PyQt5. When the user wins, I'd like to show a message with three options (buttons):

1. 'play again'
2. 'change cards'
3. 'quit'

I think the way to implement this is by using a QMessageBox, but I could not understand how to use it properly. I know it has to be something like:

```
reply = QMessageBox.question(self,
    'title',
    'text',
    button1 | button2 | button3,
    defaultButton)

if reply == button1:
    # play again
elif reply == button2:
    # change cards
else:
    # close application
```

I also know there exist `StandardButtons`, which I can use for exiting (`QMessageBox.Close`, but I am not sure), but I don't know how can I add them and other custom buttons in order to have it working.

**EDIT 1**

Ok, I think I made some steps towards the right direction, although something is stil missing.
I was able to add custom buttons to my `QMessageBox`, I am able to `print` something when one of them is clicked, but any method I call after is not doing anything. Also, if 'quit' is selected, it just closes the message box (I am using the `QCloseEvent` method, maybe it's wrong).

Here is the updated code, along with few comments:

```
msgBox = QMessageBox()
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Close)
restartBtn = msgBox.addButton('play again', QMessageBox.ActionRole)
changeBtn = msgBox.addButton('change cards', QMessageBox.ActionRole)

ret = msgBox.exec()

if ret == QMessageBox.Close:
    QCloseEvent() # should close the app, but it closes the message box
elif msgBox.clickedButton() == restartBtn:
    print('RESTART')
    self.restart # should call 'restart' method, but it doesn't
elif msgBox.clickedButton() == changeBtn:
    print('CHANGE')
    changeBtn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog) # should call 'showDialog' method, but it doesn't
```

As you can see, I tried both with `self.methodname` and with `button.clicked.connect(self.methodname)`, but none worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have worked out most of it already, but here's a complete example:

```
def showMessageBox(self):
    msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
    msg.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Question)
    msg.setWindowTitle('Prompt')
    msg.setText('Please choose an option:')
    play = msg.addButton(
        'Play Again', QtWidgets.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
    change = msg.addButton(
        'Change Cards', QtWidgets.QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
    quit = msg.addButton(
        'Quit', QtWidgets.QMessageBox.RejectRole)
    msg.setDefaultButton(play)
    msg.exec_()
    msg.deleteLater()
    if msg.clickedButton() is play:
        print('RESTART')
        self.restart()
    elif msg.clickedButton() is change:
        print('CHANGE')
        self.showDialog()
    else:
        self.close()
```

Comment: Accepted as it completes my own answer. Thank you (again)!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I realized that what I was doing was almost correct, except for missing the parenthesis after calling the methods. Now the code is running just fine, except for the fact it's not exiting the application when 'quit' is clicked (only the message box), but I will update my answer as soon as I find the way. Hope this could be a good example for anybody wanting to implement its own `QMessageBox`.

One last note: both the ways I've tried, namely calling the method itself, or calling it by prefixing the `button.clicked.connect()` method, worked for me. Maybe one is better than the other, but I judge.

```
msgBox = QMessageBox()
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Close)
restartBtn = msgBox.addButton('play again', QMessageBox.ActionRole)
changeBtn = msgBox.addButton('change cards', QMessageBox.ActionRole)

ret = msgBox.exec()

if ret == QMessageBox.Close:
    QCloseEvent() # should close the app, but it closes the message box
elif msgBox.clickedButton() == restartBtn:
    print('RESTART')
    self.restart()
elif msgBox.clickedButton() == changeBtn:
    print('CHANGE')
    changeBtn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog())
```

Answer (score 1):

self.close works as a method to close the entire application.

```
button.clicked.connect(self.close)

choice = QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.Cancel | QtGui.QMessageBox.Quit)

if choice == QtGui.QMessageBox.Quit:
        self.close()
```